# Django model.objects.get using foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

I have Model1 where I want to get a certain field based on name and last_name. My query is not working. I'm sure it has something to do with the fact that it should be searching these name fields from foreign key models. How do I do this?

```
Model1.objects.get(name=name_id, last_name="Lastname")

MODEL1
person = models.ForeignKey("Model1")
company = models.ForeignKey("Model2")
date = models.DateField()

MODEL2
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

MODEL3
name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` and `last_name` aren't part of your `Model1`, they are part of models related to `Model1` so you need to take that into account in your query and use a filter that [spans a relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
Model1.objects.get(model2__name="foo", model2__last_name="bar")
```

Comment: Great, make sure to accept the answer as correct when you can.